# How can i solve this databases reading problem with c:foreach? (If it have to do with this..)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, jsp

I did create a database with an Entity class, and I creat repository and some controller classes.

I have 3 .jsp

--> The first one is where I can take the new name, time, practice and series.
--> The second one is a simply choice method. (two submit button, first one is redirects again the first .jsp,
second one is redirects to the third .sjp)
--> The third one is.. I thought, I add a name (and click the button) and then the program list all the data for this name.

For example:

---

Adam

2010-10-01, benchpress, 2x 4db

---

I know I need to fix it in the controller class. Here is..

```
@Autowired
private BuilderService ts;

@GetMapping("ListWeb")
public String getView(String name, Model model) {
    if(name != null) {
    Builder builder = ts.findBuilderByName(name);
    model.addAttribute("datas", builder.getName());
    model.addAttribute("datas", builder.getExercise() + ", ");
    model.addAttribute("datas", builder.getSerie1x() + "x");
    model.addAttribute("datas", builder.getSerie2x() + "db");
}

    return"ListWeb";
}

@PostMapping("ListWeb")
public String postView(String name, Model model) {

    return "redirect:/ListWeb?name=" + name;
```

And my .jsp is from the form to the form.

```
<form action="ListWeb" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">List</button>
    <br>

    <c:forEach var="data" items="${datas}">
        <option value="${data.name}">${data.name}</option> <!-- I konw this is a problem, because it will be more than once.. -->
        <option value="${data.name}">${data.date}</option>
        <option value="${data.name}">${data.exercise}</option>
        <option value="${datas.name}">${datas.serie1x}</option>
        <option value="${datas.name}">${datas.serie2x}</option>
    </c:forEach>

</form>
```

My program works up to the third .jsp logic. (to the name entered, but when I push the submit button it runs away.."Whitelabel Error Page")

Error log: https://hastebin.com/pukidixava.php

Thank you!

Comment: Add error log from console to question

Comment: Builder builder = ts.findBuilderByName(name);
This call is returning 4 items instead of 1. It means that you defined a repository with a method Builder findByName(String name). You should change it to List<Builder> findByName(String name) or add a constraint that name is unique.